# How to get user machine IP using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get users machine ipAddress using java from my server.

I used the following code, and it works fine in local.

```
            URL url = new URL("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    }
```

Using this class, response shows the ip in my local web app.(localhost:8080/myApp/getIp)

I deployed this war to my AWS server, and tried to run the servlet. But this always shows the AWS ip address only. (myIp:8080/myApp/getIp)

It doesn't shows my machine IP.

What was mistake in my code, can someone assist in this?

Comment: Search before you post. [Read this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/).

Comment: *I deployed this war to my AWS server, and tried to run the servlet. But this always shows the AWS ip address only* ... *running locally works*... Right... It is the AWS making the request, so you get the AWS IP. You get your IP when you connect to that site... That's how that works.

Comment: Remember also that a machine may have more than one IP address. It is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish here, so please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() OR
2. getRemoteHost() and getRemotePort()

should returns details of the actual client

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get client ip i.e. user accessing your web-app through browser, then you can use (client-side-script)javascript to do so. Below is simple example for the same.

```js
function show(response) {
  console.log(response);
  var html = 'Something went wrong !';
  if (200 == response.geoplugin_status) {
    html = 'Got your ip as: ' + response.geoplugin_request;
  }
  document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML = html;
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.async = true;
script.src = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=show';
document.getElementById('ip').appendChild(script);
```

```html
<div id='ip'>Fetching IP ...</div>
```

Comment: This is what I already implemented. But as we have some security issues, need to go with backend. Thanks Arvind

Comment: @Clara, can you address here, _security issues_ with usage of such API ? Don't take me wrong, I am asking just for my sake of understanding.